# Regex, matches non-characters one or more times

Tags: java, regex

I'm having issues with this piece of code, specifically the code within the while loop.

```
public void mSetSafeCode() // Manually define safe passcode
{
    int mIntPasscode;
    String mStringPasscode;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your desired numerical passcode (max 3 digits): ");
    mStringPasscode = sc.nextLine();
    while(mStringPasscode.matches("\\D+") || mStringPasscode.length() > 3 || mStringPasscode.length() < 3) // If input not digit or exceeds length
    {
        System.out.print("Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: ");
        mStringPasscode = sc.nextLine(); // Prints error, gets user to input again
    }
    mIntPasscode = Integer.parseInt(mStringPasscode); // If while is not met, parses input into an integer
    System.out.println("You've set the numerical passcode to " + mIntPasscode); // Prints the passcode
}
```

I am trying to make it so while the user input from the scanner contains characters which are not digits, to throw the error. I believe my regex is correct with `\\D+` but if I were to use 'f33' as an input for example, it isn't caught in the while loop. I think this is because I'm using an or with the string length, but I want it to be caught by the while loop if it contains a character (not a digit) or if its length is greater/less than 3.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `while` loop you have:

```
while(mStringPasscode.matches("\\D+")
```

You want it to be:

```
while(!mStringPasscode.matches("\\d+")
```

Explanation:

`\\D+` matches non digits, but this will only match if the entire `String` is non digits. You want to use `\\d+` which will return false if any of the characters in the `String` are non numeric. [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) matches the *entire* `String`, so if there is a single character that does not match, it will return false.

---

```
while(!mStringPasscode.matches("\\d+") || mStringPasscode.length() != 3) 
{
    System.out.print("Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: ");
    mStringPasscode = sc.nextLine(); // Prints error, gets user to input again
}
```

***Sample Output:***

```
Enter your desired numerical passcode (max 3 digits): 34f
Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: fff
Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: 45645323
Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: ff
Error! You inputted an invalid passcode, try again: 456
You've set the numerical passcode to 456
```

Comment: I thought `\\D` was non-digit whereas `\\d` is digit?

Comment: @josef I apologize my answer was a bit unclear. Edited for clarity

Comment: thank you, that makes sense now! So `\\D+` compares the entire string, whereas `\\d+` checks any characters within the string, right?

Comment: @josef `matches()` scans the entire `String`, so no matter what the pattern, if there is a single character that does not match, it will return false

Comment: OK so `!mStringPasscode.matches("\\d+")` checks if the whole string contains anything except just digits?

Comment: @josef Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using `[0-9]{3}` will cause a match only on 3-digits.  `[\\d]{3}` would also work.

Comment: Not sure if the brackets are needed around the `\\d`, though I find `\\d{3}` works. This is easier to read though as it reduces the need for   `length()` so thank you.

Comment: The . matches any character, and the astrisk is a greedy quantifier that specifies zero or more of any character is being sought.  So, by flanking a non-digit character class, this ensures that an an alpha character can be surrounded by numbers, or what have you.  Lots of good resources on quantifiers online.  Also, check out Java regular expression planet, which is like a little sandbox for trying out various regexps. while you learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow only 3 numbers it might be better to write

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```